# Converting multi digit char to int in C++

Tags: c++

While I know that you can convert single digits that are characters to integers by doing, for example:

```
int main() 
{
    char var = '5';
    int num_var = var - 48;
}
```

I know you can't do the same thing for a character with a value which is say, '148'. Is there an easy way to convert this character value to an integer value of 148?

Comment: have you tried `int num = char_var;`?

Comment: @IłyaBursov They presumably want to parse `"148"`, so I don't think it's what they're looking for.

Comment: Don’t subtract 48. Subtract `’0’`. That’s portable.

Comment: You meantion `'148'`, but do you mean `"148"`?  Multibyte character constants don't see common usage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use atoi(buffer) function, which returns the integer from the string buffer.

You need to include <stdlib.h>

Here is the prototype of the function :

int atoi (const char * str);

Comment: That's a C function. In C++, prefer `std::stoi`, because that can report errors by throwing an exception (`atoi` just returns 0, and can even lead to undefined behaviour in some cases).

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel — `atoi` sets `errno` on an error.

Comment: @PeteBecker Ah, interesting. cppreference does not mention that at all (I had to look around elsewhere to discover that this is specifically a C99 thing, not C++).

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel The C++ standard says: `The contents and meaning of the header <cstdlib> are the same as the C standard library header <stdlib.h> ... The descriptions of many library functions rely on the C standard library for the semantics of those functions.` If some behaviour is guaranteed for library function in C, then it is guaranteed for C++. C++20 refers to the C18 standard.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel -- `errno` is also a very clunky interface; I suspect that most C++ programmers don't even know that it exists.

Answer (score 0):

> I know you can't do the same thing for a character with a value which is say, '148'. Is there an easy way to convert this character value to an integer value of 148?

Actually, the type of a (narrow) multicharacter literal is already `int`, so no conversion is needed to change the type (by converting the value to `char`, you may lose the precise value though since `char` cannot typically represent all values that `int` can). But the value of '148' is not necessarily (nor typically) 148, and there's no standard way to convert the value because the value of '148' is implementation defined.

It's of course possible to write a mapping using math for a particular language implementation if you know the mapping based on the documentation of that implementation, but such mapping isn't portable to other language implementations. Furthermore, multi-character literals are only conditionally supported, so a language implementation might not have them at all.

In conclusion: If you think that you need such conversion, then multicharacter literal is not the correct tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can't store more than one character in a char. Use a char array instead, like `char var[] = "3232"`. Then use the `atoi` function to convert to integer. `int val = atoi(var)`. Make sure to include the header `<stdlib.h>`.

Answer (score 0):

##### Case 1

First you should not use magic number like `48` etc because they make the program less portable. You should instead subtract `'0'` as shown below:

```
char var = '5';
int num_var = var - '0'; ////the result of var - '0' is guaranteed to be the integer 5
```

Here both `var` and `'0'` will be promoted to `int`. And the final result that is used to **initialize** variable `num_var` on the left hand side will be the result of subtraction of those two promoted int values on the right hand side. Moreover, the result is **guaranteed to be** the integer 5 since from [C++ Standard (2.3 Character sets)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/lex.charset):

> 3. ...In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of
>    each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be
>    one greater than the value of the previous.

##### Case 2

Suppose we have more than one characters, then one way would be to use `std::string` and `std::istringstream` as shown below:

```
std::string var = "148";
int num_var;
std::istringstream ss(var);
ss >> num_var; //now num_var is the integer 148
```